# Mount External Usb Hard Dive

Tags: mount, hard-drive

How do you mount a external USB Hard Drive latest version of Ubuntu Server 20.04.1? Can see it as `sda1` but it is not mounted. I also want it to be auto-mounted at startup. New to Linux. Any easy steps to follow? / Thanks

Comment: Usually, it goes something like this: `sudo mount /dev/sdXY`.  To automount, search for "automount fstab".

Comment: Which Ubuntu release do you mean by "latest"? Releases have version numbers.

Comment: 20.0.1 Ubuntu Server

Comment: There is no `20.0.1` release. Is it `20.04.1`? It is not the latest :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make a new directory.

```
mkdir Mount
```

Then mount the partition onto that directory.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 Mount
```

Voila.